# Which of the below countries allow retired parents to migrate to the country?

Tags: visa, immigration, resident-permit

I'm 25 years old, living in India, having Masters degree in Computer Engineering. I wish to know which of **UK, Germany, Netherlands, Poland, Canada, USA** countries would allow my retired parents to migrate permanently to the country after few years of my employment in that country. What would be the rules and conditions for the same?

Comment: Another way might just be to let them buy into some sort of investment immigration scheme, e.g. the one available in Portugal. That might actually be less of a hassle.

Answer (score 9):

**Canada**: You can sponsor your parents for immigration [once you become a permanent resident of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/family-sponsorship.html), subject to some [other conditions](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/family-sponsorship/sponsor-parents-grandparents/eligibility.html).  Permanent residents have the same eligibility to sponsor parents as do citizens, and the processing time is 20 to 24 months.

**US**: You can only sponsor your parents for immigration [after you become a US citizen](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/family-immigration/family-based-immigrant-visas.html).

**European Union (including UK [for now], Germany, Netherlands, and Poland)**: Under EU law, an EU citizen or a national of a Schengen country can bring family members fairly easily to live with them *in an EU or Schengen country other than the country of his or her own nationality.*  Parents are included in this scheme *only if they are dependent on the principal or the principal's spouse.*  This follows from [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  To do this, you would need to naturalize in an EU or Schengen country and then move to another EU or Schengen country, and your parents would need to be dependent on you.

In addition, each country has its own immigration law, but none of the named countries seems to have a route that would apply to your parents:

**UK**: You can only sponsor a parent for immigration [if you are under 18 years of age](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/parent).

**Germany**: You can only sponsor a parent for immigration [if you are a minor](https://www.berlin.de/willkommenszentrum/en/families/reunification-of-families/).

**Netherlands:**: You can only sponsor a parent for immigration [if you are a minor, and even then only in certain circumstances](https://ind.nl/en/family).

**Poland**: Family reunification in Poland is also generally limited to [spouses and "informal partners" as well as minor children](https://www.msz.gov.pl/en/p/waszyngton_us_a_en/waszyngton_us_a_en_consular_information_2/illegal_entry_consequences/marraige_reunification/).  The exception mentioned on the linked page concerns those who fall under EU law, mentioned above.

Comment: "but none of the named countries seems to have a route that would apply to your parents" - does this mean that parents cannot be immigrated to UK, Germany, Netherlands, Poland if I'm not a minor?

Comment: @user5155835 you could certainly bring them if you and they qualify under EU law as mentioned, but you cannot sponsor them under national law unless they qualify for some other route. For example, they could come to the UK for you to provide [long-term care](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/adult-dependent-relative) if you are settled in the UK and the care they require is unavailable or unaffordable in their country of residence. If they are financially independent and healthy then you will probably not be able to bring them.

Comment: @user5155835 Some other EU countries (France, Spain, maybe Portugal) have long-stay visas for the financially independent, which your parents may be able to qualify for in their own right, though the cost of living is I suppose so much higher in those countries than it is in India that I suppose many retired couples who have very comfortable lives in India might not have sufficient means to qualify for these visas.

Answer (score 4):

For Canada it’s just not as simple as sponsoring . You must be a PR, must meet the cutoff for LICO. Must show three years of income . You apply and hopefully get picked out of the pool, there’s only a set number of applications allowed . Working prior is generally not allowed, unless under extremely narrow set of rules